# How to remove whitespace from the output of the following script?

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
for i in range(1, 4):
    print i,
```

Output is `1 2 3`, but I want the output like `123`, i.e without spaces,
so how to do it?

Comment: Create the string you want *then* print it?

Comment: no string is not allowed

Comment: Not allowed as in "You can't `print "123"`", or as in you can't use `''.join()` either?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In python2, you have to use `sys.stdout.write()` to avoid the spaces inserted by the `print` command:

```
import sys
for i in range(1,4):
    sys.stdout.write(str(i))
sys.stdout.flush()
```

Edit: as noted by GPhilo, you can also use python3's print *function* that has the option of avoiding separators, after importing it from `__future__`.

Answer (score 1):

As a technical note, while you should definitely **not** print this way if what you want is one string, it's doable with Python 3's print:

```
from __future__ import print_function
for i in range(1, 4):
    print(i, end='')
```

See the other answers for how to do this building a string instead.

Comment: I was not aware of this that we can change print deliminator in python3.X

Comment: We can indeed, and there's a lot more that [`print_function`](https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#print-is-a-function) can do

Comment: My answer is for python 2. In python 3 you don't need the `__future__` import